# Does unlocking a primary weapon in prestige mode unlock all attachments?

Tags: call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

As the title suggests, wondering if unlocking a weapon will unlock all attachments via prestige mode?

Comment: It never has previously, so I doubt it'd be different this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no information to suggest this. So I guns will be based on prior games and you will have to unlock your attachments.

Comment: Technically, prestiging should not reset your challenges on the weapon, so I guess if you unlocked attachements before prestiging, you should keep them. But I haven't checked that yet.

Comment: @rdurand prestiging does reset your weapon challenges, it doesn't reset any earned camos.

Comment: @turbo : reseting weapon challenges was a bug corrected in this week's patch, live now on all platforms except the 360 (should be fixed in the upcoming days)

Comment: @rdurand oh I wasn't aware, haven't had time to play this week, my mistake!

Comment: @turbo : looks like even after the patch, the weapon challenges for equipment are reset. You loose all attachements and have to unlock them back. Weapon camo challenges do not reset though.

Comment: @rdurand I suppose that's good, weapon challenges are a good source of exp